# Mysql select to table 5 per line

Tags: mysql, database

how i can Select from mysql_db to table limit by 5. 5 per line.
I have:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

i need:

```
1 6 11
2 7 12
3 8 13
4 9 14
5 10
```

or :

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14
```

thank you.

Comment: Consider handling data presentation in your presentation layer.

Comment: And you tried whàt exactly?

Comment: try to display data as in the example and we will help you , think about **modulo % operator**

Comment: I agree with @MostyMostacho ... it seems silly to try doing what you're trying to do. MySQL is not a data displaying program. It's just there to help you get data in and out. I would use, say, PHP to help me output a nice HTML table to display my data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapte this function according to your case :

```
<?php
$array=array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');

function display($array,$limite){
    $arrays= array_chunk($array, $limite);
    foreach($arrays as $array){
    echo implode(' ',$array).'<br/>';
    }
}
display($array,2);
?>
```

**Output of `display($array,2);`**

```
a b
c d
e f
g
```

**Output of `display($array,3);`**

```
a b c
d e f
g
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will solve your problem. Table named test is joined to himself two times on the interesting condition:

```
SELECT
    t.num as num,
    t1.num as num1,
    t2.num as num2
FROM
    test t
    LEFT JOIN test t1 ON(t.num+5 = t1.num)
    LEFT JOIN test t2 ON(t1.num+5 = t2.num)
ORDER BY num ASC
LIMIT 5
```